# Arithmetic operations on objects

Tags: javascript

I am looking into an existing library and I am confused about the use of arithmetic operations on objects.

The objects which have been used for arithmetic operations look like this:

```
{
  _high: 0,
  _low: 256,
  remainder: { _low: 0, high: 0, remainder: null }
}
```

They have been used like this:

```
const id = {
  _high: 0,
  _low: 256,
  remainder: { _low: 0, high: 0, remainder: null }
};

while (id > 0) {
  const remainder = Math.floor(id % 14);
}
```

**Question:**

What exactly happens if one applies an arithmetic operation like modulo on an object or compares it with a number?

If possible rewrite the given snippet to something which uses the object properties.

Comment: @NinaScholz See the comment. It would return an object like the given example above.

Comment: @NinaScholz That's exactly my question, I don't get it either, but it works. You can test it yourself. I noticed that it would return false if (all?) properties are 0 (and null?) and it will return true if one number (e. g: `_low` is higher than 0)

Comment: JavaScript will attempt to convert the object to a number by calling the `.valueOf()` method. That's explained in intricate detail in the language spec.

Comment: @NinaScholz I haven't written the code. The snippet I posted however "works" and whoever wrote it, knows exactly what it does and took "advantage" of it. I want to rewrite it to use a property of the object but therefore I have to understand what exactly it does. That's why I have created this SO.

Comment: @NinaScholz it will call `.valueOf` and use what it returns; in this case it returns an object. The posted code does not "work" in any sense of course.

Comment: @Pointy What returns an object ? If we try to copy OP's example, the operation as a whole, will use a string (the result of `toString` on the object), not an object.

Comment: @Taurus the greater than and less than operators (`>` and `<`) prefer numbers to strings, so the language will attempt to coerce the object reference to a number. In any case your answer is correct :)

Comment: `The posted code does not "work" in any sense of course.` this made me believe you thought OP's code would throw a `TypeError`, I must have misunderstood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You Don't Know JS: types & grammar, chapter 4](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md):

> Objects (and arrays) will first be converted to their primitive value equivalent, and the resulting value (if a primitive but not already a number) is coerced to a number according to the ToNumber rules just mentioned.
>
> To convert to this primitive value equivalent, the ToPrimitive abstract operation (ES5 spec, section 9.1) will consult the value in question (using the internal DefaultValue operation—ES5 spec, section 8.12.8) to see if it has a valueOf() method. If valueOf() is available and it returns a primitive value, that value is used for the coercion. If not, toString() will provide the value for the coercion, if present.
>
> If neither operation can provide a primitive value, a TypeError is thrown.

So, I am assuming that your object has a `valueOf` method that returns a number, so in both arithmetic operations that you are performing on your object, that method is called to coerce the object into a number, and the resulting value is what's actually used in the operation.

---

Also, your example is quite useless since it doesn't include that underlying `valueOf` method, when we try to do something like `id + 10`, we get `[object Object]10`, why is that ? The default `valueOf` is failing to provide a primitive, so then `toString` is consulted, which returns `[object Object]`, that primitive value is then concatenated with `10`, which results in `[object Object]10`.

To better understand this, take a look at these examples:
1.

```
const id = {
_high: 0,
_low: 256,
remainder: { _low: 0, high: 0, remainder: null },
valueOf: function(){
return 20; /* valueOf does not fail to provide a primitive, "20" will 
be used". */
},
toString: function() {
return 10; /* toString's return value would be used (if it was a primitive), if "valueOf" failed to provide a primitive. */
}
};


console.log(id + 10); // prints out "30"
```

2.

```
const id = {
_high: 0,
_low: 256,
remainder: { _low: 0, high: 0, remainder: null },
valueOf: function(){
return {}; // valueOf fails to provide a primitive
},
toString: function() {
return 10; // toString provides a primitive value, so "10" will be used.
}
};


console.log(id + 10); // prints out "20"
```

3.

```
const id = {
_high: 0,
_low: 256,
remainder: { _low: 0, high: 0, remainder: null },
valueOf: function(){
return {}; /* valueOf fails to provide a primitive */
},
toString: function() {
return {}; /* toString fails to provide a primitive as well */
}
};


console.log(id + 10); // a "TypeError" is thrown :(
```

Answer (score 1):

answer: method .valueOf() is called
you may implement your own logic there.

```js
var obj = {
 a: 11,
 b: 30,
 valueOf: function () {
    return this.a + this.b;
 }
}

if (obj> 40) {
     alert(obj + 1);
}
```

Comment: but in general is a bad idea to build your flow based on casting object to string or a number; much better is moving appropriate logic to some well-named methods like `if (obj.isStillAlive()) ...`

Comment: I agree, but there has to be an advantage as well ? something that balances the disadvantage of having confusions such as OP's.

Comment: @Taurus don't see any. It's always confusing that new Date() + 1000 returns number not Date object.
it could be helpful if default logic of Array.prototype.sort() used .valueOf() instead of .toString() to compare elements. 
But unfortunately it is not(say, array of Date is sorted by string representation - so all the Fridays first and all the Wednesdays last)